# What chemicals could be added to human urine to cause harmful chemicals to precipite out?

Tags: biochemistry, aqueous-solution, catalysis, precipitation

What chemicals could be added to human urine to render it drinkable with no harmful side effects?

[Urine is salty and contains other dissolved solids](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urine). Thus, drinking untreated urine would result in osmotic pressure actually removing water from the body.

So, what chemicals would be needed to cause the salts and other dissolved solids to precipite out or otherwise be rendered harmless?

I am thinking about a tablet, capsule or drops that would render human urine drinkable within 5 minutes or so.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/58528/what-chemicals-would-need-to-be-added-to-human-urea-to-make-it-a-nutritional-sub

Comment: Yes, that is my original question. Should I consolidate the two questions or address them separately?

Comment: If they are separate - one has to do with urea, this one is a little more broad - then they can remain as-is. It boils down to: if this question and the other ones are "the same," then one of them needs to go. If they are demonstrably different, they remain separate. You can simply clarify if they are dupes or not.

Comment: I'm still interested in any ideas for transforming the chemicals in urine into a nutritional substance, or at least nutritionally neutral.

Comment: There isn't any magic chemical that would make urine drinkable in the way that you're describing. You can reformulate the question 100 ways and there still won't be any such magic chemical.